# How to replace all the occurences of chars like '[' , '(' etc with '\[' , '\(' using "sed" in a file?

Tags: shell, scripting, sed, vim

I have a file "say file.txt" with following contents:

```
Capsule arr[0] in state A
rate_ul/dl=(2000000/7000000)
Capsule RBx[0] in state
...
...
```

using sed operator how can i replace all occurences of `[` with `\[`, `(` with `\(`, `]` with `\]` and so on.

```
Capsule arr\[0\] in state A
rate_ul/dl=\(2000000/7000000\)
Capsule RBx\[0\] in state
...
...
```

Using the substitue operator in "gvim" I am able to achieve the same result.
ie. if i use `:1,$ s/\[/\\[/g` in the vi editor in command mode I see all the `[` chars replaced with `\[`.

However if I try to use the same substitue command in a shell script using a sed command, i am not able to achieve the same result.
ie If i use the following command in a shell script I am not able to achieve the desired result:

```
sed "s/\[/\\[/g"  $temp_file2 > $temp_file1
where $temp_file2 conatins the lines with '[' characters and $temp_file1 should contain the replaced '\[' chars
```

Comment: Inside double quotes, you would need to escape the backslash: `sed "s/\[/\\\\[/g"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 sed 's/[][()]/\\&/g' infile > outfile
```

#### Output

```
$ sed 's/[][()]/\\&/g' infile
Capsule arr\[0\] in state A
rate_ul/dl=\(2000000/7000000\)
Capsule RBx\[0\] in state
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy !! Possible use of double-quotes was the cause that is was not working for me.

Comment: @Abhijeet I optimized it down to only one `sed` script

Comment: I didnt know that. SO has really been helpful to me. I ll do that from now on. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

gawk version

```
gawk '{gsub(/[()\]\[]/,"\\\\&")}1' file
```

Comment: You don't need all the escapes if you use `/[][()]/`